# How to read elements in header as is in R?

Tags: r, read.table

I want to read in a normal .txt file with a header that contains some numbers like this:

```
Samples 1e-2 1e-3 1e-4
Apple   200   150  100
```

After using:

```
myf<-read.table("file.txt",header=T)
```

the resulting myf header becomes:

```
Samples X1e.2 X1e.3 X1e.4
```

So my question is how do I read the header the way I wanted?

Thanks!

Comment: Look for the `check.names` argument to `read.table()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `check.names` = FALSE

```
> read.table(header = TRUE, text = "1e-2 1e-3 1e-4
+ 200   150  100", check.names = FALSE)
  1e-2 1e-3 1e-4
1  200  150  100
```